# Why use `return x == 5 ? true : false;`?

Tags: java, boolean

I can not see the advantage of this coding practice. The project I'm working with now is full of these statements so it is not a single mistake.

Another example:

```
return getNumberOfBooks() > 5 ? true : false;
```

And another:

```
return isRed() ? true : false;
```

Comment: :-D This very much resembles what my classmates did at our programming class in high school. Like for example `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { if (i == 1) puts("1"); else if (i == 2) puts("2"); else puts("3"); }`. Ergo, it seems to me like someone's misunderstanding that a boolean value that comes out of comparison is just as good as one given by constants.

Comment: Somebody had a fascination with ternary expressions.

Comment: @Imp:  Ironically enough, the output would be "3", "1", "2".

Comment: @Makoto Eh, my mistake :) But you get the point I wanted to illustrate ;)

Comment: That's a code redundancy and tools might even warn about that and suggest to simplify.

Comment: People indeed get creative sometimes, I've seen things like "myBool |= true" in real code :).

Comment: `myBool |= true` is actually valid in Java. When the operands are `boolean`s, the | and |= operators are considered logical and not bitwise :-)

Comment: @Kos I sometimes save true and false in variables when coding JavaScript. It makes the code smaller when you minimize it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to do this.

It is redundant and makes the code harder to read.

The following are far easier to read:

```
return ( getNumberOfBooks() > 5 );

return isRed();
```

Comment: Even the braces `( ... )` in the first return is not needed.

Comment: I don't find that *more* readable. I'm sure many wouldn't either.

Comment: Of course it's not _needed_, but I feel it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @jahroy - ..unless one knows about operator precedence.

Comment: Not sure how precedence applies when there's only one operator...

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are working on a project with newbie programmers. Start refactoring where ever you see:

```
return getNumberOfBooks() > 5 ? true : false;
return isRed() ? true : false;
```

change it by:

```
return getNumberOfBooks() > 5;
return isRed();
```

Comment: Better yet: `return ( getNumberOfBooks() > 5 );` That's even more readable (in my opinion and as per the coding conventions).

Comment: @jahroy you are right but that's just a detail :P

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator makes the code almost unreadable, 
thought its a smart way of coding, but should not be encouraged unless really needed

Comment: Agreed... Abuse of the ternary operator drives me nuts!

Comment: yup..... you are right... Any fool can write a code that a computer can read, but only great programmers write codes that human can read

Comment: ... And for some reason, tons of programmers take pride in writing gimmicky, hard to read code.  Readability is the #1 most important thing when writing code (once you get it to work properly).

Comment: @jahroy Yes **abuse** of the operator drives me nuts too, but when used effectively (i.e. for relatively simple operations), I think it helps make your code more readable.  It shrinks some 4 lines of tedious code into 1 line.  Pulling an example out of my head: `File file = ...; return (file == null) ? null : file.getPath();`

Comment: @jahroy Also, if the boolean test has any whitespace in it, I always surround it with parens to make it more readable (like in my example above).

Comment: Completely agree.  I use it, but only in special cases.  I generally use it if it is VERY straightforward and the entire line is less than about 70 characters.

Comment: @Michael - Totally agree.  Parens make comparisons much easier to read in my opinion.  Oracle's coding conventions also suggest the use of parens in this situation.

Comment: Actually, I think code readability is the most important thing in *getting* code to work properly so that, chronologically, it comes before the properly working code.

Comment: The problem with the `bool? true : false` construct isn't the ternary operator at all - implementing it with if/else certainly wouldn't be better!

Answer (score 2):

Clearly this is unnecessary redundancy.

I suggest doing so in Eclipse:

1. find all that matches regexp "return (something) ? true : false" and replace it with just `something`
2. and all that matches regexp "return (something) ? false : true" with !(something)

You can delegate writing this regular expression to those who has written this project :D